# Compound literal in an array definition

Tags: c

Consider this array:

```
unsigned char* array[] = { (unsigned char[5]){}, (unsigned char[5]){} };
```

Does `array[0]` and `array[1]` still point to a valid memory even after the complete definition of `array`? Meaning, afterwards I am allowed to do for example
`memcpy(array + 1, "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", 5);`

Comment: Not sure you need the extra dimension here.

Comment: Please update your question to show a small complete program including that declaration. The semantics of a compound literal differ depending on whether it appears inside a function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that declaration appears outside of any function, then `array` and the compound literals have static storage duration, so they exist for the duration of program execution, and you can use them at any point in the program.

If the declaration appears inside of a function, then `array` and the compound literals have automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block. Using the memory of the compound literals is defined as long as using `array` is defined.

Note that `{}` is not a strictly conforming initializer; you should give at least one value, as in `{0}`. (GCC and other compilers may accept `{}`.)

Comment: Note however that empty `{}` initializer lists will become valid C as per C23.

Answer (score 2):

> Does `array[0]` and `array[1]` still point to a valid memory even after the complete definition of `array`?

Yes.  The lifetime of a compound literal, if not declared at file scope, is that of its enclosing scope.  So the following code:

```
unsigned char* array[] = { (unsigned char[5]){}, (unsigned char[5]){} };
memcpy(array + 1, "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", 5);
```

Would be valid, however an empty initializer list is not allowed in strictly conforming code although many compilers support it as an extension.  A fully compliant example would be:

```
unsigned char* array[] = { (unsigned char[5]){0}, (unsigned char[5]){0} };
memcpy(array + 1, "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `array[0]` and `array[1]` are valid as long as `array` is valid.

Quoting the standard's description of compound literals:

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
> initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
> outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
> duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
> the enclosing block.

You have two unnamed array objects of type `unsigned char[5]`, and the address of each object's initial element is used to initialize an element of `array`.

If the definition is at file scope (outside any function body), then the unnamed array objects have static storage duration, meaning that they exist during the entire execution of the program.

If the definition is inside a function body, at block scope, then the lifetime of the anonymous array objects ends when execution reaches the end of the enclosing block -- which is the same as the lifetime of the `array` object.

Note that the `{` and `}` of the initializer do not form a "block".

(C23 will allow more control over the lifetime of objects created by compound literals. It will also make `{}` a valid initializer; in current C, though some compilers allow it as an extension, it's not permitted by the language.)